# Magento 1.9.2.2 Free Shipping Coupon Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, free-shipping

Currently we are using Magento version 1.9.2.2 and out free shipping coupon is not working correctly, I have set up a product cart rule in which if cart subtotal is >=100 and place by General or Guest user then he get free shipping. I have also create another coupon for 50% off on shipping if order is >=299 and placed by wholesale which is working correctly.

Where as the coupon is applied and also excluding the shipping amount but it also exclude the amount from cart item as well and adding the subtotal amount to shipping price.

I have already attach the screen shot so it would be easy to rectify the error. It would be great if any one update me which file is adding the discount on item row in cart.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your setup is working correctly. You are saying $100 & Shipping discount for cart. If you are only looking for FREE SHIPPING, have that $100 to $0 and mark `Free Shipping` to `Yes`. That should give free shipping.

Comment: Hi I have tried what you saying but that one is also not working, its says coupon applied but there is no changes appears on shipping price. Please have a look: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3281202/3adc5a8abb475c1f12898d860458e10d

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my issue by changing Discount.php in /app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote there is a foreach loop in which discount is applied to each line item i have make changes in this file to restrict shipping coupon applied on line item.

need to edit this function: _aggregateItemDiscount() which is calling from foreach loop to apply discount to line item